# vue dom get inner value without id

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dom item like blow:

```
<div data-realindex="0" class="img-item-wrapper"><div class="img-item" style="margin-bottom:8px;display:;" data-a-b8815d2c=""><div aria-label="图片.图集.共undefined张" class="img-wrapper__4hevL img-container img-wrapper-radius-tl__FrE43" style="height: 0px; padding-bottom: 100%; border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(&quot;http://mms1.baidu.com/it/u=690465849,3185922056&amp;fm=253&amp;app=138&amp;f=JPEG?w=500&amp;h=667&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"><!----><div><div><!----><div class="half-mask__bdYCX"></div><!----></div></div><!----><!----></div><!----><div><div class=""><div><!----></div><!----></div></div></div></div>
```

[image]

The item have nested child, and I need to get the background-image in the inner child's style string.

```
background-image: url:(htttpxxxxx)
```

Can I just for loop key values to get background-image directly?

Comment: Is this dom element dynamic?

Comment: If you can target the DIV via `querySelector` - then you can inspect the element's `style.backgroundImage` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by accessing the style attribute based on the class name and then access the required style property along with the value from it.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('img-container')[0]

const styles = el.getAttribute("style").split(';');

for(var i=0;i<styles.length;i++) {
    eachStyle = styles[i].split(':');
  if (eachStyle[0].trim() === 'background-image') {
    console.log(styles[i].trim())   
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-realindex="0" class="img-item-wrapper"><div class="img-item" style="margin-bottom:8px;display:;" data-a-b8815d2c=""><div aria-label="图片.图集.共undefined张" class="img-wrapper__4hevL img-container img-wrapper-radius-tl__FrE43" style="height: 0px; padding-bottom: 100%; border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(&quot;http://mms1.baidu.com/it/u=690465849,3185922056&amp;fm=253&amp;app=138&amp;f=JPEG?w=500&amp;h=667&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;"></div></div></div>
```